# How do I change a button to have a custom image in CustomTkinter

Tags: python, pycharm, customtkinter

so im tryna make a window using CustomTkinter; how do I change a button to have a custom image?

I've tried: button = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="xyz", image="xyz.ico", command=button_callback)
(and everything else that it needs to fucntion), but it just gives me an error stating the image doesnt exist. I've tried using a png and an svg, but it gives me the same message.

Expected: Work as expected

Tried: Following the online manual(s) and going through the list of cmds.

Comment: The `image=` option needs to be an actual image object (generally of type `PhotoImage`, rather than a string that is perhaps the filename of an image.

Answer (score 0):

**import the path of your directory like this**

```
image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "images")
```

**This is how you can show your button image as you want you can modify**

```
  minimize_img = customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open(os.path.join(image_path, "minimize.png")), size=(18, 18))
  minimize = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.title_bar, text='', command=lambda:self.hide_screen(), fg_color="#000000", width=30, image=minimize_img, hover_color="#40c7ff", corner_radius=0)
  minimize.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky="e")
```